# Sharepoint 2013 App/Add-ins - one workflow multiple lists

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, sharepoint-2013

I have 10 list instances based on the same template (CT) deployed in a Sharepoint 2013 Addins.

I would like to associate a workflow to theses list instances.

The trigger should be item updated.

Moreover i would like to pass a different value in a workflow arguments (ex text value)

Is it possible to run any type of scripts when an app / add ins is installed

(powershell or javascript)

Second option, is it possible to trigger a workflow with javascript when a item is updated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you write an event receiver in C# in Visual Studio 2013, it will catch each ItemUpdated event no matter for which list. WARNING: It also catches events from updates in system lists - hence you should either deactivate the event workflow whilst updating system issues or much better check your list names in the workflow in your event and levae all other lists run into event default behaviour.